# Set partition with special constraints

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, constraints

Does anybody has an idea how to find formula for *S*(*n*) defined as:

*S*(*n*) = min {*k* ϵ N; for all partitions *A*<sub>1</sub>, *A*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *A*<sub>*n*</sub> of set *A*={1,2,...,*k*} ∃*i*  ∃*a*, *b*, *c* ϵ *A*<sub>*i*</sub>: *a*+*b*=*c*}

It is obvious that *S*(1) = 2, *S*(2) = 5.... But how to define formula for *S*(*n*) in general?

Comment: Yes, you are right... my mistake... but have you got any idea to some general formula? Thanks

Comment: @DrXorile: No, it must work for **all** partitions of $[k]$ into $n$ parts. For each of those partitions there must be at least one part with the desired property.

Comment: I am sure that there is for all partitions, because of this detail it is amazing problem...

Comment: @sybarite: I’ve not yet really thought seriously about it. $S(1)=2$ and $S(2)=5$ suggest that if it’s something familiar, it might be the Catalan numbers, but two data points aren’t enough to give me even a tiny bit of confidence. If you feel like trying another case by hand, the next Catalan number is $14$, but $n=3$ is getting rather messy.

Comment: $S(3)=14$. I just checked. I can post the result below

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but Brian Scott conjectured in the comments to the question that it was the [Catalan numbers](https://oeis.org/A000108). If so, it's probably worthy of inclusion in the list of results on the OEIS page.

Anyway, a simple python script demonstrates the following:

```
For n=2:
Checking with k = 2
No Ai exists for [[1], [2]]
Checking with k = 3
No Ai exists for [[1], [2, 3]]
Checking with k = 4
No Ai exists for [[1, 4], [2, 3]]
Checking with k = 5
S(2)=5
```

and

```
For n=3:
Checking with k = 3
No Ai exists for [[1], [2], [3]]
Checking with k = 4
No Ai exists for [[1], [2, 3], [4]]
Checking with k = 5
No Ai exists for [[1, 4], [2, 3], [5]]
Checking with k = 6
No Ai exists for [[1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 6]]
Checking with k = 7
No Ai exists for [[1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 6, 7]]
Checking with k = 8
No Ai exists for [[1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
Checking with k = 9
No Ai exists for [[1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
Checking with k = 10
No Ai exists for [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 6], [3, 8, 9, 10]]
Checking with k = 11
No Ai exists for [[1, 5, 8], [2, 6, 7], [3, 4, 9, 10, 11]]
Checking with k = 12
No Ai exists for [[1, 4, 10], [2, 3, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
Checking with k = 13
No Ai exists for [[1, 4, 10, 13], [2, 3, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
Checking with k = 14
S(3)=14
```

which certainly fits Brian Scott's conjecture.

The next one is computationally challenging. I've established that $k>21$, but it will take a while to get to 42. This is a simple, brute-force kind of code. There are probably cleverer ways to do this...

```
For n=4:
Checking with k = 4
No Ai exists for [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
Checking with k = 5
No Ai exists for [[1], [2, 3], [4], [5]]
Checking with k = 6
No Ai exists for [[1, 4], [2, 3], [5], [6]]
Checking with k = 7
No Ai exists for [[1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 6], [7]]
Checking with k = 8
No Ai exists for [[1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [8]]
Checking with k = 9
No Ai exists for [[1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]
Checking with k = 10
No Ai exists for [[1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10]]
Checking with k = 11
No Ai exists for [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 6], [3, 8, 9, 10], [11]]
Checking with k = 12
No Ai exists for [[1, 5, 8], [2, 6, 7], [3, 4, 9, 10, 11], [12]]
Checking with k = 13
No Ai exists for [[1, 4, 10], [2, 3, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [13]]
Checking with k = 14
No Ai exists for [[1, 4, 10, 13], [2, 3, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [14]]
Checking with k = 15
No Ai exists for [[1, 8, 11, 14], [2, 6, 10, 13], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 12, 15]]
Checking with k = 16
No Ai exists for [[1, 5, 9, 12, 15], [2, 6, 11, 14], [3, 7, 8], [4, 10, 13, 16]]
Checking with k = 17
No Ai exists for [[1, 6, 9, 13, 16], [2, 7, 12, 15], [3, 8, 10], [4, 5, 11, 14, 17]]
Checking with k = 18
No Ai exists for [[1, 9, 11, 14, 17], [2, 5, 6, 13, 16], [3, 8, 10], [4, 7, 12, 15, 18]]
Checking with k = 19
No Ai exists for [[1, 5, 8, 12, 15, 18], [2, 6, 10, 14, 17], [3, 4, 9, 11], [7, 13, 16, 19]]
Checking with k = 20
No Ai exists for [[1, 9, 11, 13, 16, 19], [2, 6, 7, 10, 15, 18], [3, 4, 5, 12], [8, 14, 17, 20]]
Checking with k = 21
No Ai exists for [[1, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20], [2, 5, 6, 9, 16, 19], [3, 7, 12, 13], [4, 10, 15, 18, 21]]
```

This is after running overnight...